# Buttons need to be tapped twice in order to fire the click event on iOS

Tags: ios, tabs, toggle, tap

When I access at this [link](http://dp2.wlthemes.com/listing/example-listing-6/) from iOS the button with the symbol of the clock needs to be tapped twice in order to show the opening hours. This problem affects also the other buttons.

The first tap is handled like a mouseover event.

[image: IMAGE OF THE FIRST CLICK]

How can I fix this problem?

This is the code of the button with the clock:

```
<li><a href='#openinghours' data-toggle='tab' title='Opening hours'>
<span class='round-tabs four'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></span>
</a></li> 


<div class="tab-pane fade" id="openinghours"> 

 <!--html content  of the opening hours-->

</div>
```

On the desktop version of the website everything is working well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment, but I would clear all your JS errors on your page before you start to debug this. You seem to have around 6 console errors and 2 warnings.

I've tried this in my Simulator, and it behaves as you say - however the W3C Bootstrap 4 Nav Tabs are fine. Therefore, I'd suggest looking at the difference (as well as seeing if any errors are interfering)

Link to w3 Schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_nav_tabs_toggleable&stacked=h

Comment: Do you think that if i fix the 6 console errors this problem will be also fixed?

Comment: I upvoted you so you can now insert comments, please move this to a comment

Comment: Thanks @Ibo, I've included the link Daniele to the bootstrap 4 example of Navigation Tabs. They work on my iOS simulator, therefore - I would conclude there is something interfering.